# Can't log Out of Xubuntu

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, session, logout

I install `xubuntu-desktop` in a fresh ubuntu 14.04 system.  When I was using the xubuntu desktop environment, I click "logout" in the top panel and the following dialog appears

[image]

But nothing happens after I click "Log Out".

Instead, if I run `xfce4-session-logout` from the terminal, another dialog appears (I can't take a screenshot) which allows me to "Log Out" or "Restart" or "Shut Down" or "Suspend".  So how could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Installing `xubuntu-desktop` environment, Now you can use `xfce4-session-logout` directly from Whisker menu as following screen-shot:

[image: logout_screen]

The option you mentioned in question is **Session Management** (`com.canonical.indicator.session`) provided by **Indicator Plugin** and can be hidden as following screen-shot:

<sup>I experienced that some options are not working properly so I hide it because there is no requirement of session management indicator in Xubuntu</sup>

Goto **Panel>items** & Edit Indicator Plugin:-

[image: penalconfig]

Hide Session Management:-

[image: hide]

Then logout and login back to show effect.

---

Additional Information: In Xubuntu, You can simply call `xfce4-session-logout` by shortcut **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>** (from active desktop)

Comment: That's very clear, but I still want some other features from the session management (like suspend). Why doesn't the logout work and how can I investigate this further?